# Keylogger Extension

Tags: python, python-2.7, keylogger, psutil

I need assistance in how to divert text that is currently on the Python window into a text log (`handlelogs.txt`) that that uses the psutil module. The idea is to display disk partitions and it does work just to the wrong location. Below is code which provides information needed. Thank you everyone. Also keylogger will not be used in a malicious manner.

```
keylog = ""
current_window = ""
filename = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "\\handlelogs.txt"

dps = psutil.disk_partitions()
fmt_str = "{:<8} {:<7} {:<7}"
print(fmt_str.format("Drive", "Type", "Opts"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A keylogger wouldn't help with this, because you never type the data with your keyboard. What you're really asking is how to send output from `print` to a file instead of the terminal window. That is possible, but it's easier just to write the data to a file using the standard `file.write()` method.

This should work:

```
import os, psutil

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "handlelogs.txt")
dps = psutil.disk_partitions()
fmt_str = "{:<8} {:<7} {:<7}\n"

print("Saving partition data to {}.".format(filename))

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(fmt_str.format("Drive", "Type", "Opts"))

    for dp in dps:
        f.write(fmt_str.format(dp.mountpoint, dp.fstype, dp.opts))
```

Comment: Thanks for help but the information printed still displays on the terminal window rather than in the log.

Comment: Which line do you mean? The `print()` call should show text in the terminal, but the `f.write()` calls should put text into `handlelogs.txt`. Is something different happening?